# calculate and show the solutions in the complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers

This is a (difficult for me) task from complex numbers that I cannot solve. At the same time, I know the basic rules of complex numbers, but I simply do not know how to solve this.

$$\sqrt[4]{-1+i\sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: I always default to using complex exponential form of complex numbers.

Comment: That is new for me... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complex exponential form is $re^{i\theta}$, where $r$ is the modulus, and $\theta$ is the phase, or angle the number makes with positive real axis when plotted in the complex plane.  The number inside root lies at the point $(-1,\sqrt{3})$ in Cartesian plane, where $y$-axis is imaginary part, and $x$-axis is real part.

Pythagorean theorem is used to find modulus:
$$r = \sqrt{(-1)^2+(\sqrt{3})^2} = 2.$$

I will let you compute the angle, $\theta$.

Then,
$$\sqrt[4]{-1+i\sqrt{3}} = (re^{i\theta})^{1/4} = r^{1/4}e^{i\theta/4}.$$

After this, to write result is standard form, you would use Euler's formula:
$$re^{i\theta} = r(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)).$$